# flying saucer PDF generation with Image will it work on linux server?

Tags: macos, nullpointerexception, itext, freemarker, flying-saucer

I'm able to generate the pdf with images using custom implementation of `RelacementElementFactory` from xhtml template using `Freemarker`.

> But I got an error when my system screen was off, hence pdf didn't generated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.getScreenResolution(LWCToolkit.java:356)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.SharedContext.<init>(SharedContext.java:110)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:111)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
```

> Why this happened...?
>   [NOTE: I'm using OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.4]

I have failed to reproduced this by running several time my server when system screen is locked and not displaying anything.

> Will it impact on other OS machines(like linux machine server) ...? or is this MAC OS related only and does not impact on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As mentioned in the question issue was not reproducible.
- Since question was to know flying saucer PDF generation with Image will it
  work on linux server?

> Answer is yes it is working without any issue.